# How to pass arguments to Spring Repository when using it with a Spring Application or while testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've created a Spring repository, that allows the user of this repository to add and remove from a MySQL table. Now to be able to use this repository, the application/tester would need to pass in the datasource variables (viz URL of the database, usermame, and password).

I tried having arguments to my constructor for the repository, but it seems that that is not allowed.

From what I've read online, one way is to use @Value annotation, and use that to pass it in. However, does this also work if the applciation.properties is not in the same file as the repository? By that I mean, like, the person making the application would put the application.properties file in the directory of the application right? And not in the directory of the repository? How do I do it in that case?

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Here is the code for my repository right now:

```
@Repository
public class SigningKeyDao implements IDao<SigningKeyModel> {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    SigningKeyRowMapper wrapper = new SigningKeyRowMapper();

    private String tableName = "signingKey";

    public SigningKeyDao(String url, String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.dataSource =
                DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url).username(username).password(password).build();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

And this is how I am using this repository in my test class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.supertokens.repository")
@SpringBootTest(classes = SigningKeyDao.class)
@EntityScan("com.supertokens.model")
public class SigningKeyTableTest {

    SigningKeyDao dao;

    public SigningKeyTableTest() {
        this.dao =
                new SigningKeyDao("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/st_maven", "root", <password>);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to setup `SigningKeyDao` in `@Before` section instead of constructor. https://www.baeldung.com/junit-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-beforeall

Comment: @Sebastian can that function take in arguments?

Comment: Ou wait, you try to create spring bean by constructor. This cannot be done, when you try to create the object of type `SigningKeyDao`the method annotate by `@PostConstruct` wont be invoke. You need to create this bean by injection and there will be no way to pass arguments, Or just delete @PostConstruct and create `JdbcTemplate` in your `SingingKeyDao` constructor.

Comment: Don't do things like these, please don't. Just configure the `spring.datasource` properties and Spring Boot will automatically construct a `DataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` and the latter you should inject into your class. The Dao will also be pre configured for your test, you don't need to construct it yourself, else the `@SpringBootTest` annotation would be pretty much useless. Instead of `@SpringBootTest` you might want to use `@JdbcTest` instead.

Comment: I was able to pass the configuration from the tester to the repository using application.properties in the test folder itself! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

To set an application property to a certain value in a particular test, have a look at the @TestPropertySource annotation which allows you to change the value of one or more properties from the application.properties file for the scope of the annotated test-class.
Example:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.supertokens.repository")
@SpringBootTest(classes = SigningKeyDao.class)
@EntityScan("com.supertokens.model")
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "spring.datasource.url=custom_url_just_for_this_test",
    "spring.datasource.username=user",
    "spring.datasource.password=secret"
})
public class SigningKeyTableTest {
```